# How do I add to a column instead of a row using Bash Script and csv?

Tags: bash, csv

```
#!/bin/bash
# This file will gather who is information

while IFS=, read url
do
    whois $url > output.txt
    echo "$url," >> Registrants.csv
    grep "Registrant Email:" output.txt >> Registrants.csv
done < $1
```

How do I get the grep output to go into a new column instead of a new row? I Want column 1 to have the echo, column 2 to have the grep, then go down to a new row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the trailing newline on echo with the `-n` flag.

```
#!/bin/bash
# This file will gather who is information

while IFS=, read url
do
    whois $url > output.txt
    echo -n "$url," >> Registrants.csv
    grep "Registrant Email:" output.txt >> Registrants.csv
done < $1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use printf, then you don't have to worry if the "echo" you are using accepts options.

```
printf "%s" "$url,"
```

printf is much more portable than "echo -n".